# How to save the stdout and stderr to a file while still seeing the output?

Tags: shell, python

I'm trying to debug a program that generates a lot of data. But the event which I want to debug happens after a random amount of time (I cannot force it). So I would need to see the stdout and stderr in my shell and save the same output to a file for further analysis and interrupt as soon as I see what I need on my shell output.

I found the `script` command on this [ask Ubuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485495/how-to-both-display-a-command-lines-output-on-console-and-save-the-output-into) but I cannot get it to work, script says :

```
$ script "./client -p 4242 -n test"
Script started, output file is ./client -p 4242 -n test
```

and then exits. The file contains:

```
Script started on Thu Jun 26 13:51:12 2014

Script done on Thu Jun 26 13:51:12 2014
```

**So `script` doesn't work**. The `./client` file is a python script. I also tried launching it with `$ python client -p 4242 -n test` but it's not working either.

I also saw on the same thread some answers with `tee` and a pipe but I can't get it to output to my shell and see what is going on:

```
$ ./client -p 4242 -n test | tee output.log
```

gives me a waiting cursor without nothing happening. **So `tee` doesn't work**.

Is there any other solution or am I doomed to wait and interrupt the program after some time and hope it went through the event I'm looking for ?

Thank you much for your help !

P.S. I'm on zshell (with oh-my-zsh), Mac OSX 10.9.3, Python 2.7.5

**EDIT:** I may have to mention I'm using the `multiprocessing` module and the `./client` script launches multiple other `Process`es. Could it be for that reason ? Still I don't understand why it won't catch the `./client` process output...

**EDIT2:** I tried the answer from Matteo below (thanks a lot for your help) and it keeps getting stranger and stranger:

If the process fails (the server is shutdown), I can see the output:

```
$ ./client -p 4242 -n test 2>&1 | tee output.log
Process Process-1:
Client # 1: Could not connect to server. Stopping.
Spawner: New client # 1 started...
Done.
$
```

but if it looks like it's running, I see nothing:

```
$ ./client -p 4242 -n test 2>&1 | tee output.log
^C [voluntary interrupt after a lot of waiting]
$ cat output.log
$
```

In the log above (where it fails), you can see that the new process prints *before* the main one (`Spawner`) even though it started after it. So it looks like some really strange output magic.

Comment: If `tee` and `script` aren't capturing the program's output, then the program may be doing something more "clever" than just write to stdout/stderr. It may be writing to /dev/tty, or it may alter its behavior when stdout/stderr isn't a TTY.

Comment: The only function I'm using is the `print` statement from Python (2.7.5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect standard error to standard output and then use [`tee`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee) to duplicate standard output and store it to a file.

```
$ ./client -p 4242 -n test 2>&1  | tee output.log
```

**Edit**: you can try out the command by

```
$ ( echo "stdout" ; echo "stderr" 1>&2 ) 2>&1  | tee output.log
```

The two `echo`s produce output on both stdout and stderr. You should see both, and the same in `output.log`

**Edit**

Instead of modifying your program (flush) you could also try `script -q` or several other tools as mentioned in [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)

Comment: I tried this because it was suggested in the ask Ubuntu thread but there is no output on the shell when I try it. And the output.log file is empty ! I don't understand why :/ Is it the python 2.7 "print" statement ?

Comment: @matteo's answer is the normal way to do what you've asked. It's possible that this "client" program behaves differently when stdout/stderr isn't a TTY.

Comment: BTW I tested on OS X 10.9.3 with zsh and it's behaving as described.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Unfortunately, it keeps getting more and more strange (see second edit). I'll wait some more in case someone knows where this could be coming from (python ? multiprocess ?).

Comment: Your answer is the correct one in a "general case". But didn't work for me because of some specificities (Python multiprocessing module).

Answer (score 1):

Victory !

As mentioned in the question, I was using python's `multiprocessing.Process` to spawn new processes from the main client. Because of that, the output was buffered and waited for the buffer to be full before flushing but it seems that it never happens with the `| tee` command. Thus never printing anything and waiting endlessly.

Thus, **the solution is to add a `sys.stdout.flush()` after every `print` statement** as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367053/no-print-output-from-child-multiprocessing-process-unless-the-program-crashes):

```
print "Player # " + int(self.id) + " joined the map"
sys.stdout.flush() #<==== THIS MAKES IT ALL WORK !
```

After that, Matteo's answer works like a charm and it's possible to have the output on the shell and in the text file at the same time.

```
$ ./client -p 4242 -n test 2>&1  | tee output.log`
$ cat output.log
Player # 1 joined the map.
Player # 1 updated it's inventory.
[...]
```